# Odd BitmapRegionDecoder java.io.IOException: Image format not supported w/ png and jpeg images

Tags: bitmap

I do not understand why I am getting this IO Exception. It says in the docs `"Throws
IOException if the image format is not supported or can not be decoded."` and `"he stream's position will be where ever it was after the encoded data was read. Currently only the JPEG and PNG formats are supported."` and I am giving it a PNG, I even output the image type by using `bitmapOptions.outMimeType;` and it says `image/png`

Code :

```
    @Override
protected List<String> doInBackground(String... urlo) {
    List<String> savedKeys = new ArrayList<String>();
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    try {
        URL url = new URL("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/47/PNG_transparency_demonstration_1.png/280px-PNG_transparency_demonstration_1.png");
           HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.connect();
           inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }   



    BitmapFactory.Options bitmapOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    bitmapOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream, null, bitmapOptions);
    int width = bitmapOptions.outWidth;
    int height = bitmapOptions.outHeight;
    String imageType = bitmapOptions.outMimeType;
    Debug.out(imageType);



    int block = 256;
    int count =0;
    BitmapRegionDecoder decoder = null;
    try {
        decoder = BitmapRegionDecoder.
            newInstance(inputStream, false);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Rect tileBounds = new Rect();
    // loop blocks
    for (int i=0; i<height; i+=block) {
        // get vertical bounds limited by image height
        tileBounds.top = i;
        int h = i+block<height ? block : height-i;
        tileBounds.bottom = i+h;
        tileBounds.right = 0;
        tileBounds.left = width;
        Debug.out(tileBounds.left+" "+tileBounds.right+" "+tileBounds.top+tileBounds.bottom);
            // load tile
        tile = decoder.decodeRegion(tileBounds, bitmapOptions);
        MainActivity.cache.put(key+count, tile);
          publishProgress();
          tile.recycle();
        savedKeys.add(key+count);

    }
    try {
        inputStream.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return savedKeys;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exeption is not thrown because of the wrong filetype, but because it was not readable.

```
BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream, null, bitmapOptions);
```

This "traverses" the stream, and your stream object no longer start at the beginning.

The solution is to call `inputStream = connection.getInputStream();` again after this, to return the stream to it's orignal readable state.